# How do I select this check box using Selenium/Java

Tags: selenium, xpath

Can someone help me create a path that will allow me to click this checkbox?

I have a page that features around 50 boxes like this one where the only difference is the text (in this case Answer Flow Designer). I am creating a script that will take a string array and iterate through it selecting each matching checkbox.

```
<td class="normal">                                                                                        
    <input name="1.48.1.3.2.6.1.1.57.3" type="checkbox" value="0">Answer Flow Designer
</td>
```

Comment: IMO, you need to show us a bit of the outerHTML till we find an unique attribute to locate the `WebElement` of our interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below to match required `input`:

```
//td[contains(., "Answer Flow Designer")]/input
```

Note that you cannot use

```
//input[contains(text(), "Answer Flow Designer")]
```

as `input` node **cannot contain any child nodes** (attributes only) and `"Answer Flow Designer"` is actually child text node of `td`

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, Andersson.  That makes total sense - I wondered why many xpaths were written that way, and now I better understand.  I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @BillHileman, `input` node has no closing tag (`</input>`), so `<input name="1.48.1.3.2.6.1.1.57.3" type="checkbox" value="0">Answer Flow Designer` might be misinterpreted  as `<input name="1.48.1.3.2.6.1.1.57.3" type="checkbox" value="0">Answer Flow Designer</input>`

Comment: @JackTaylor, welcome. You can [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the whole html looks lets say

Now you first need to get the Number of inputs tag inside td tag for that use

```
     <td class="normal">                                                                                        

     <input name="1.48.1.3.2.6.1.1.57.3" type="checkbox" value="0">Answer 
     Flow Designer/>
     <input name="anything new" type="checkbox" value="0">Another text/>
     <input name="anything new" type="checkbox" value="0">Another text/>
     <input name="anything new" type="checkbox" value="0">Another text/>
     .
     .
     and last 50th 
     <input name="anything new" type="checkbox" value="0">Another text/>
     </td>
```

iterate them like below and get the text as well from each elements

```
        List<WebElments> tdtagselements=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[1]//input")); 

      for(int i=1;i<tdtagselements.size();i++){
      String textInputtag=driver.findelement(by.xpath("//td[1]//input["+i+"]")).gettext();
}
```

use this string to compare with the text you want to verify your text
let me know how exactly your html code looks like

Answer (score -1):

```
//input[@type='checkbox' and contains(text(),'Answer Flow Designer')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I thought the 'and contains' feature might be right. Problem is though Im getting a no element found error - no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='checkbox' and contains(text(),'Answer Flow Designer')]"}

Comment: Based on the HTML segment you showed, I see no problem with the path.  Can you expand on the page source?

Comment: Sorry to be prohibitive but the page source is really large and there might also be some sensitive info. Is there anything I should look out for that you could recommend? Thanks again

Comment: @Ashley Mills to whom is your comment directed?

Comment: Nevermind, you clearly meant me.  I don't see the point in your critique but I suppose "rules is rules"

Comment: Sorry @BillHileman - this was an automated comment from the review process. What it should say is something like "better answers provide additional explanation, rather than just code"

Comment: That makes much more sense, thanks for clarifying that for me.

Answer (score -1):

As this checkbox has name, you can use it.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("1.48.1.3.2.6.1.1.57.3")).click();
```

If name is not unique and you want find element by following text, you can use

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(., 'Answer Flow Designer')]//preceding-sibling::input")).click();
```

Comment: Your second example needs "By.xpath"

Comment: Thanks for the response. The name is identical in all boxes so I cant use that. However, whilst I am fully confident your second solution should work (as another user submitted the same) I am getting a no element found error. Do you have any ideas why this could be? As far as I am aware there are no iframes in use on the page. Edit: this includes using .xpath

Comment: @JackTaylor Have you tried with an explicit wait on these checkboxes?

Comment: Please try following code and tell me if it works: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(., 'Answer Flow Designer')]//preceding-sibling::input")).click();

Comment: Just tried the explicit wait and no luck -  Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //input[@type='checkbox' and contains(text(),'Answer Flow Designer')]. Will now try illegal arguments suggestion.

Comment: Ok I am now getting a ElementNotVisibleException